# ActiveRecord appends 'AND (1=0)' to end of queries

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I've been playing around in the rails console trying to get things to work, and I notice that one of my queries keeps returning nil when it shouldn't.  Upon looking at the generated SQL query I notice that it has `AND (1=0)` appended to it each time.  This is kind of annoying, and I'm not sure why it's doing this.

*Note:* Using the actable gem.

Steps to reproduce:

(After connecting to tables in rails console)

```
2.1.2 :xxxx > @parent = Parent.take
Parent Load (38.1ms)  SELECT  `parents`.* FROM `parents`  LIMIT 1
 => #<Parent id: 37, ...>

2.1.2 :xxxx > @child = Child.where(id: @parent.actable_id)
SQL (0.7ms)  SELECT `childs`.`id` AS t0_r0, `childs`.`attribute` AS t0_r1, FROM `childs`
...
LEFT OUTER JOIN `parents` ON `parents`.`actable_id` = `childs`.`id` AND `parents`.`actable_type` = 'child type' WHERE `childs`.`id` = 20 AND (1=0)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Why is this happening? How do I make it stop?

Comment: I notice that Rails does this for this query: `User.where(:id => [])`, since you can't write `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id in ()` in SQL. So I guess this is the approach is takes for queries it knows will return nothing, but it can't express in SQL.

Comment: @MaxGabriel this was the answer for me.  Maybe put this as an answer instead of just a comment?

Comment: @jgraft Good idea, I made this an answer like you suggested.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Rails will generate SQL like `AND (1=0)` when you query for a column whose value is in an empty array:

```
Child.where(id: [])
```

Intuitively, you'd expect that to generate SQL like `SELECT * FROM children WHERE id IN ()`, but `()` isn't actually valid SQL. Since no rows will match that query, though, Rails works around this by generating an equivalent query that also returns no rows:

```
SELECT * FROM children WHERE 1=0;
```

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped me out with the same confusion! Too bad it was never accepted as the correct answer.

Comment: @alex0112 Would you consider accepting this answer?

Comment: This also seems to happen if you specify empty hashes
Child.joins(:parent).where(:parents => {})

Comment: Yep, confirmed with a test query. Thanks @OliverKruster

Comment: Thanks for the instant clarification, I was already wondering where it came from but a quick google search saved me probably hours, what I don't understand is, if Rails actually executes the query (runs it against the DB) when it knows it'll return no rows, why bother with running it?

Comment: I'm not certain, but ideas would be: 1) The query that returns nothing could be a subquery that's part of a bigger query which actually does return results, or modifies database state in some way 2) It adds complexity to the implementation 3) It might be unexpected for developers that a database query doesn't actually hit the database